# Website with https (SSL) do not open in IE and Safari

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, ssl, safari, centos

Recently I setup SSL certificate for my website. Everything works good (using **https**) in **Chrome** and **Mozilla Firefox** but website do not open at all in **Internet Explorer (IE)** and **Safari**. Following (please check image URL) is the error I see when I try to open website.

I have set redirection to https from http in my .htaccess but I don't think this is the problem here.

[image: Website not working in IE and Safari with https]

SSL is properly set, I have checked with multiple online SSL checkers and SSL certificate includes www.website.com and website.com as well.

Other details of my server are

**PHP:** 5.5.29

**Apache:** Apache 2.4.6 CentOS

**OpenSSL:** OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

**SSL (Registered Stream Socket Transports):** tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls

**TLS** 1.2

Thanks in advance,

Comment: See if this helps: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53562/safari-cant-connect-to-https

Comment: @GoinOff, Thanks. 
I was able to add certificate in trusted certificate at my local machine but being a developer I want that users don't these messages and website (https) should open without any issue just like in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either Enable TLS 1.0 in IE => internet options => advanced => security or downgrade to apache 2.2